# Why are Precognitive and Beta badges awarded?

Tags: discussion, support

Can someone tell me the significance of these badges:

> **Precognitive** : Followed the *Area 51* proposal for this site before it entered the commitment phase
>
> **Beta** : Voted 10 times, added 3 posts score > 0, and visited the site on 3 separate days during the private beta

My questions:

1. What is this **private beta**? Is it meta ?
2. I went to the *Area 51* link but understood nothing about what the badge is awarded for.

Can anyone pitch in with an answer?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[Area51](http://area51.stackexchange.com/) is where new sites are incubated. Sites proposals have several phases, and user can "follow" a proposal while it is still being defined, then commit to it. When enough people commit, it will launch.

Launched sites are initially (seven days) available only to people who committed to the proposal. That initial period is called the private beta. It is followed by an open beta when anyone can join.

So, both these badges are awarded for participating in the creation process of a site and can not be earned by users who join later.

---

Note that Stack Overflow, Meta Stack Exchange/Meta Stack Overflow, Server Fault and Super User are exception to that flow as they predate Area51.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Can I participate in such a thing or do I need a higher reputation? Can you please provide the steps I need to follow? I don't know where I have to go to form a new site or commit to one.

Comment: @Aniket you have to go to [area51.SE]. There are only minimal reputation requirements (or none, perhaps, I'm not sure). As dmckee said, you won't be able to earn these badges on any existing sites, but you could earn them on new sites that will be formed in the future.